# How is change detection performed with Outputs in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a Parent and Child component with an Output binding:

```
<parent>
  <child (doStuffChild)="doStuff()"></child>
</parent>
```

A user click causes `doStuffChild.emit()`.

1. What's the order of the events that follow: does `doStuff()` method in the parent get called first and then change detection happens from the root?
2. Does the invocation of `doStuff()` in the parent also happen inside the `Zone.run()` started by the click?
3. Does change detection eventually happen because the click eventually led to a `zone.onTurnDone()` event?
4. What lifecycle hooks get called and in what order? (i.e. Do onChanges/doCheck get called in the parent or child?)
5. If ngOnChanges gets called, why does that happen? I thought NgOnChanges only gets called for inputs. (After reading [this article](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2017/01/18/angular-2-change-detection-seeing-it-in-action/#comment-93143) I'm assuming ngOnChanges gets called)

I'm happy to clarify my question if it's too confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes
2. `doStuff()` is run inside Angulars root zone, no need for an additional `Zone.run()`
3. change detection happens because Angular knows about `@Output()`s and when events are emitted
4. `onChanges` won't be called, because no `@Input()` is changed. `ngDoCheck()` is run when change detection is run after `doStuff()` was called